# Django/Apache - read files from network drive (Windows)

Tags: django, windows, apache, smb, network-drive

I have been working in windows environment for producing & deploying django for internal use at work and been asked to add a feature to read files saved at the network drive (ideally, .xlsx file view). So, I would want to list .xlsx files in a specified folder in the network drive and let the user view the file if clicking on it.

My first approach was to create a user account with "Log on as a service" and "Act as part of the operating system," and run the Apache using this account. But, later realized I can't inherit the access to the network drive my admin account has (or is it possible?).

And, I decided to run it with my admin account, which I know is not a good idea to do in production, but wanted to see that I am on a right track... Tried below config but I am stuck at how to proceed from here to achieve the feature described above.. /l/ is an alias of the UNC of network drive.

```
<Directory /l/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I tried SMB to try connecting but connection error has been returned (not even sure it is applicable in my case). Can anyone please at least guide me whether I am walking in the right direction..?

Comment: For retrieving files from the network the SMB approach is the default one, especially if you are using windows. you can open a wireshark and sniff the network packet, and you can understand what was the connection error type. It sound like a credentials issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Eliad. Can you please guide me on the parameters for the SMB connection (userid, password, client_machine_name, server_name, server_ip)? So, I have a server that is hosting the django web app and is mounted with a network drive. I am little confused with the context of "server" here. Is the server_ip/server_name the ip/name of my hosting server? or is it some other server that is related to the network drive?

Comment: we can continue this topic on the SO [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205374/room-for-eliad-cohen-and-yoobin-jeon)